# How do I set the colorAxis of a googleVis bubble chart?

Tags: r, googlevis

I try to adapt the GoogleVis bubble chart [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html) with a continuous color scale for the bubbles based on the profit column:

```
library(googleVis)
Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", 
                          xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                          colorvar="Profit", 
                          options=list(
                              ## custom color
                              ## colors = "['red', 'green', 'blue']",
                              ## custom color scale does not work
                              colorAxis="{colors: ['yellow', 'red']}",
                              hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}'))
plot(Bubble)
```

However, whatevery I try with the 'colorAxis' option it does not work, while I do follow the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart). It seems weird, because when I look at the source code of the plot I can see that the option is set:

```
// jsDrawChart
function drawChartBubbleChartID2b6add84971() {
var data = gvisDataBubbleChartID2b6add84971();
var options = {};
options["colorAxis"] = {colors: ['yellow', 'red']};
options["hAxis"] = {minValue:75, maxValue:125};
    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(
    document.getElementById('BubbleChartID2b6add84971')
    );
    chart.draw(data,options);   
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **UPDATE:**

After I added an [issue](https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/81) on GitHub, the problem should be resolved for the current developer version on GitHub (`devtools::install_github("mages/googleVis")`). And indeed, it works:

[image]

---

The problem seems to be the data column "Profit":

```
var datajson = [
                ["Apples", 98, 78, "20"],
                ["Oranges", 96, 81, "15"],
                ["Bananas", 85, 76, "9"]
               ];

data.addColumn('string','Fruit');
data.addColumn('number','Sales');
data.addColumn('number','Expenses');
data.addColumn('string','Profit');
```

For reasons I do not see this column is defined as a `string` type column. When you change the relevant lines to

```
var datajson = [
                    ["Apples", 98, 78, 20],
                    ["Oranges", 96, 81, 15],
                    ["Bananas", 85, 76, 9]
                   ];

data.addColumn('number','Profit');
```

a gradient color scale is applied to the bubbles.

This might be a bug in the `googleVis` implementation since the `Fruits` data defines the Profit column to be numeric.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you very much. Not only for reporting the issue, but I now also learned how I could have diagnosed the problem myself (look at the datajson). I will install the dev version!